# Can't set ID to Dynamixel MX-64

Tags: dynamixel

I have 2 WidowX robots which I already successfully address ID's for all the MX-28 and AX-12A servos using ROS code in the Arbotix controller with the Dynamanager 1.3 on a Mac **but I can't detect any the MX-64 servos**.

When I hit the scan button, it's searching forever and end up finding nothing.

I always plug one servo at a time, and also tried each of both connector on the MX-64 servo and also use a known working servo wire.

There is something more that I should do to address MX-64 servos ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: upvote ... well presented question